# Does Parrallel win 10 work well for Macbook 12" 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, office-365

Does Parrallel win 10 work well for Macbook 12" 2016 ? I am going to buy new MacBook 12" as it is so cool. However, I need to use Microsoft Office 365 for my work with full compability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) will work with any reasonably new Mac with [relatively little performance hit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvcxPufSRNo). It uses [virtualization technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), and should suit your needs.

With that said, [MS Office 365 is compatible with OS X](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-365-home), so I'm not sure why you'd need to use a VM at all.

Comment: Mac Office 2016 still misses out on a lot of functionality present in Windows Office 2016 - especially in the level of VBA and Macro support, for example.

Comment: @Dai Fair enough.